# Prefix the result of a XPATH query

Tags: xpath, libxml2, libxml-js

I use libxmljs to parse some html.

I have a xpath query which has an "or" conjunction to retrieve basically the information of two queries

Example

```
doc.find("//div[contains(@class,'important') or contains(@class,'overdue')]")
```

this returns all the divs with either important or overdue...

Can I prefix or see within my result set which comes from which condition?

The result could be an array with an index for the match 0 for the first condition and 1 for the 2... Is this possible...

Or how can I find out which result comes from which query condition...

Thanks for any help...

P.S.: this is a simplified exampled of a sequence of elements which either have an important or an overdue item ... both, one or none of them... So I cannot go by looking for every second entry ... etc

This is the result I want to get...

```
message:{},
message:{
   .....
  important: "some immportant text",
  overdue: "overdue date,
  .....
}
```

Comment: So why would having two separate queries not be a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know which clause of an `or` XPath query caused a particular result to be included.  It's simply not information that's kept around.

You'll either need to do entirely separate queries for `important` and `overdue`, or do one large query to get the entire result set (as you are now) and then further test each result's class to find out which one it is.